# I am almost to London. This sentence is correct?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, sentence-construction

If I want to tell someone that **I am almost to a specific location**, What should I say ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing ungrammatical about "I am almost to London" although, at least in the US, it would be more idiomatic to say something like "I have almost got to London" or "I am almost in London." In this context, "to" would more commonly be used with a verb denoting directed motion rather than some form of the verb "be," which does not necessarily imply any motion at all.

Answer (score 0):

`I'm almost to {place}` doesn't necessarily imply that the place is your destination. It could be a point along the journey.

> I'm almost to Avondale.

could be a progress report about how far you've traveled on your journey, or it could mean that you have almost reached your destination, Avondale.

If the person you're speaking with knows your destination, you can say

> I'm almost there.